# Issue with passing unwrapped reference to Objective C initializer

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

`PhotoCollectionViewDelegate` has initialiser -

```
-(instancetype)initWithController:(MyViewController *)controller {
    self = [super init];
    if(self) {
        self.myViewController = controller;
    }
    return self;
}
```

Calling this from `MyViewController.swift` file,

```
let photoCollectionViewDelegate = PhotoCollectionViewDelegate(controller : self)

gives 'Can not convert value of type MyViewController to expected argument type 'MyViewController!'
```

i.e `PhotoCollectionViewDelegate(controller : MyViewController!)` but `self` with which it is called is `MyViewController`.

Comment: yes, but not sure how to get  MyViewController! (optional value) using self, as self gives MyViewController (unwrapped value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be dumb but have you tried:

`let photoCollectionViewDelegate = PhotoCollectionViewDelegate(controller : self as MyViewController!)`

Comment: No luck, gives - 

Cannot convert value of type '(NSObject) -> () -> MyViewController' to type 'MyViewController!' in coercion

Answer (score 1):

Give it a try:

```
let optionalSelf = self as MyViewController!
let wrappedSelf = optionalSelf ?? nil
let photoCollectionViewDelegate = PhotoCollectionViewDelegate(controller : wrappedSelf)
```